# verilog reg as loop counter cannot use the max number

Tags: verilog

I wrote a module using a `for` loop:

```
reg [3:0] i;
always @ ( a or b )
begin
    for ( i = 4'h0; i <= 4'hf; i = i + 1'b1 )
    //some code
end
```

I believe it should be ok to compile, but vivado say "loop limit exceed".

If I change `reg[3:0]` to `reg[4:0]`, everything is alright.

I'm confused why my current code doesn't compile; is there a mistake I made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is that you have created an infinite loop.  The end condition of the `for` loop will never be true.  The maximum value of the 4-bit `reg` is 15 (4'hf).  When i=15, executing i=i+1 sets i=0 again.  By extending your `reg` by one more bit, you increase the max value to 31, and you avoid the infinite loop.

More conventionally, you would change:

```
reg [3:0] i;
```

to:

```
integer i;
```

Answer (score 0):

In a for loop the variable is changed until the condition is false.

Thus first `i` is incremented (`i = i + 1'b1`) and then the code checks if the for loop should be executed. For i==15 the value is still true so the loop is executed. Then the increment takes place: 15+1 but this gives 0, which is still true. Thus you have an infinite loop.